# MS access query not running correctly in excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

The following query is running correctly in MS Access 2010 but when running in MS Excel 2010 it returns less records.

```
SELECT Population.[Country Grouping], Population.[Legal Staff Country], Population.[Service Line], Population.[Indirect Function], Population.Corporation, IIf(IsNull([Q_Man_SEC_Moodle.DAS])=False,"Successful",IIf([Q_Man_SEC_Successful.History Status]="Successful","Successful",IIf([Q_Man_SEC_InProgress.History status]="Not Evaluated","Not Evaluated","Not Registered"))) AS Result, 1 AS [Counter]
FROM ((Population LEFT JOIN Q_Man_SEC_Successful ON Population.[User Name] = Q_Man_SEC_Successful.[Learner Das id]) LEFT JOIN Q_Man_SEC_InProgress ON Population.[User Name] = Q_Man_SEC_InProgress.[Learner Das id]) LEFT JOIN Q_Man_SEC_Moodle ON Population.[User Name] = Q_Man_SEC_Moodle.DAS;
```

I think the issue is in the `Isnull([Q_Man_Sec_Moodle.DAS]) = False` part. 
It looks like these records are not included.
the `Q_Man_Sec_Moodle` query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Moodle Data].DAS
FROM [Moodle Data]
WHERE ((([Moodle Data].SCORM) Like "*SEC_AW*") AND (([Moodle Data].[completed?])=1))
GROUP BY [Moodle Data].DAS;
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution, so will share it here. Excel doesnt accept LIKE with * as wildcard. Changing it to ALIKE and using % solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

So like this?

SELECT DISTINCTROW [Moodle Data].DAS
FROM [Moodle Data]
WHERE ((([Moodle Data].SCORM) ALIKE "%SEC_AW%") AND (([Moodle Data].[completed?])=1))
GROUP BY [Moodle Data].DAS;

Comment: Yes exactly like that.